# How to copy a collection from one mongodb to another?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named tracks in a db named socialmedia in my mongo. How can i copy this collection to another mongodb in my network  ?

**Update:**
there is only one mongodb instance

Comment: I'm missing the point of your "Update". Do you want to copy to another machine or just another collection? "another mongodb in my network" seems to imply another machine or instance. So which one is it?

Comment: mongodb in another server

Comment: Then I think you got an answer. You can "accept" that you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cloneCollection`
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/

On the target server, run

```
{ cloneCollection: "databaseName.socialmedia", from: "mongodb.example.net:27017" }
```

If you wanted to do this on the same server:

```
db.socialmedia.copyTo(newNameOfSocialmedia)
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/

Answer (score 7):

Export your collection to file, copy the file to the other machine and import it on your other machine.

Export from commandline to file:

```
mongoexport -d socialmedia -c tracs -o filename.json
```

Import a file(in the same folder) from commandline :

```
mongoimport -d socialmedia -c tracs --file filename.json
```

Comment: I am not sure about this, but `copyTo` should only work within one MongoDB instance, right? This question makes not clear if two instances are used.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect - can use cloneCollection

Answer (score 0):

Use mongo import and export. Explanation you [can find here](http://artem-gryn.net/mongo-import-export/)

```
mongoimport --db project_test_db --collection users --out export/users.json

mongoexport --db project_test_db --collection users --sort '{fieldName: 1}' --limit 100 --skip 10 --out export/users.json
```